# Difference between boost async_write() and non_blocking socket.send()

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

'Cause we can set a socket to non blocking state by its member function `non_blocking(true)`.

Is there any difference between `async_write(socket, buffer)` and non_blocking `socket.send(buffer)`?

Will multiple `socket.send(buffer)` result in out-of-order data delivery, as the same the `async_write(socket, buffer)` does?

Answer (score 1):

**send** does not guarantee you that all data was written to socket. You should check out "bytes written" return value, error codes etc. In other hand, **async_write** will try to send until all data is sent or error occur.

Remarks from [ip::tcp::send](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/send/overload3.html) manual:

> The send operation may not transmit all of the data to the peer.
>   Consider using the write function if you need to ensure that all data
>   is written before the blocking operation completes.

Comment: Thanks. Will multiple `socket.send(buffer)` result in out-of-order data delivery, as the same the `async_write(socket, buffer)` does?

Comment: @StephenW no, `send` cannot do that since its one-step method and `async_write` is not. Note `send` can do that anyway if you ignore its return value =)

Comment: Even `send` is one-step method, since we set socket to non-block state, will `send` turn into a nonblocking function? Thus we might call multiple `send`s, resulting in out-of-order delivery.